# Where is Data Source=MvcMovie.db?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, razor-pages

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio-code

I am trying the Visual Studio Code following the above tutorial to create Razor Pages which I did manage to run successfully to perform CRUD for Movie model. What puzzle is me when I look at the appsettings.json, it has

"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MovieContext": "Data Source=MvcMovie.db"

My question is, where is my database of the above configuration? It looks very different from my Visual Studio Community IDE. I understand one is xml and another is JSON. But this JSON data source didn't specify which sql instance name?

Comment: It seems a normal SQLite database file. It is created (in not existant) when the code run and open the connection

Comment: oic. thanks for the info. how do i replace sqlite to sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the startup class, you will see in the method `ConfigureServices` something like this

```
services.AddDbContext<RazorPagesMovieContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(
        // This is one way to get your connection from the appsettings.json
        // the result of this call is: "Data Source=MvcMovie.db"
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("MovieContext"))
    );
```

Comment: how do i replace sqlite to sql server?

Comment: You need to install this package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`  and instead of `UseSqlite` add `UseSqlServer`.